# Atom feed basics

Tags: java, rest, servlets, rss, atom-feed

I want to provide a atom feed. My HttpServlet writes the following stuff (copied from wikipedia):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"><author><name>Autor des Weblogs</name></author><title>Titel des Weblogs</title><id>urn:uuid:60a76c80-d399-11d9-b93C-0003939e0af6</id><updated>2003-12-14T10:20:09Z</updated><entry><title>Titel des Weblog-Eintrags</title><link href="http://example.org/2003/12/13/atom-beispiel"/><id>urn:uuid:1225c695-cfb8-4ebb-aaaa-80da344efa6a</id><updated>2003-12-13T18:30:02Z</updated><summary>Zusammenfassung des Weblog-Eintrags</summary><content>Volltext des Weblog-Eintrags</content></entry></feed>
```

I'm writing this stuff directly with `response.getOutputStream().write(message.getBytes());` with message being the string above.

In Internet explorer a special feed reader page is opened but with firefox the raw xml is displayed.

Is this a firefox issue, or am I missing to pass some encoding,header, mime type or other information that all browsers see that a atom is coming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the correct content type, which for Atom is application/atom+xml because this is what your browser uses to decide what plugin or app to launch.

Answer (score 1):

Did you use the correct response header for your atom feed. You need to set "Content-Type:application/rss+xml" in your response header for this to properly work in firefox.

Comment: This is the right idea, but the wrong media type - see my answer below.